# Use Gnome along with Unity

Tags: unity, gnome

I have a question, could be dumber one. If I install Gnome 3.12 in my Ubunutu-14.04 would I be able to use both Unity and Gnome? I mean is there a way to switch from Gnome to Unity by logging out?

I'm installing Gnome via

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Adding that repository will break unity.

Answer (score 0):

It will work just fine if you install gnome shell from the official repository. You can choose the desktop in the login screen else you will be automatically logged on to the last selection.

Also during install you can choose between the lightdm and gdm greeters, the first is the default and the second is the gnome one (both should work fine with unity and gnome). the greeter is basically the login screen.